# Why does Symfony 3.4 form displays EntityType choices with label although 'label' => false was used?

Tags: forms, symfony

I am working on an existing `Symfony 3.4` based project and trying to add and render a new form. Although the `'label' => false` option was used, the fields are rendered including a label. Why?

```
// Symfony
class SomeController extends Controller {        
    public function userListAction(Request $request) {  
        $users = $someService->getUsers();

        $formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('users', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => false,                  // also tested '' and 'someLabel'
                'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
                'choices' => $users,
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
            ]);

        $variables = array(
            'form' => $formBuilder->getForm()->createView(),
        );

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Pages:user_list.html.twig', $variables);
    }
}


// Twig
{% extends 'AppBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block page_content %}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

This shows a list of checkboxes for all users **including the username as label**.

Where does Symfony get the information to use the username as label? As far as I know no custom form widget was defined for the `User` class. Is there any way to check this for sure? Maybe there is something hidden in the vendor bundles like `FOSUserBundle`?

**Why is the `'label' => false` option ignored?**

---

### Edit:

Different ways of rendering the form does not solve the problem:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_row(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}

Result:
<div id="form_users">
     <div class="form-group">
         <div class="checkbox">
             <label for="form_users_547">
                 <input type="checkbox" id="form_users_547" name="form[users][]" value="547"> 
                     someUserName
             </label>
         </div>
      </div>
 </div>



{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}

Result:
<div id="form_users">
         <div class="checkbox">
             <label for="form_users_547">
                 <input type="checkbox" id="form_users_547" name="form[users][]" value="547"> 
                     someUserName
             </label>
         </div>
 </div>



{{ form_start(form) }}
    {% for userFormView in form.users %}
         {{ form_row(userFormView) }}
    {% endfor %}
{{ form_end(form) }}

Result:
Basically the same as before with form_row
```

Comment: Symfony uses the __toString method inside the entity to get the text for the label. Use 'choice_label' to change this behavior https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label

Comment: @Vyctorya Thanks, using `choice_label => false` did the trick and the label text is not shown any more. However, the rendered HTML code still contains `<label for"...">...` but no text in it. This seem unnecessary if no label is included... It is possible to get rid of this as well?

Comment: You can change the theme and generate labels only if there is text inside. I always use {{ dump(form.yourfieldname.vars.block_prefixes) }} to find out which block to change. https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#creating-a-form-theme-in-the-same-template-as-the-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ‘choice_label’ => ‘YOUR PROPERTY PATH’ in the field options.

Pretty match is written in the docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label

If the entity class cast to string then is used if is not it will throw an exception. It looks like your entity User cast to the user name and that’s why it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use `{{ form_row(form) }}` which should render the whole field correctly.

Comment: Thanks but this does not solve the problem with the label but only changes the surrounding HTML by adding a `<div class="form-group">`